# I need to include dynamic js and css file inside my views folder in laravel 5.3 So I need to use any Laravel url function to simply point the files

Tags: php, laravel

I am developing a project in Laravel 5.3, in some pages I need to include some additional js and css files for some pages dynamically, so I need to know that is there any Laravel url functions that points to the view folder inside resource folder.

I have the following code in my app.blade.php

```
// for CSS
 @if(isset($data['css']))
        @foreach($data['css'] as $css)
            {{-- Include the css files --}}
        @endforeach
 @endif

// For js
@if(isset($data['js']))
     @foreach($data['js'] as $js)
         {{Request::url()}}
         <script src="{{$js}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
     @endforeach
@endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make it from your `AppServiceProvider` or you can make new service provider  and use vie composer to share this variable
like this:

```
  $CSS = [
        'select2' => '     <link rel="stylesheet" href="' . asset('admin/css/components/select-boxes.css') . '" type="text/css"/>
                           <link rel="stylesheet" href="' . asset('admin/css/components/select2-bootstrap.css') . '" type="text/css"/>',
        'select2-general' => '     <link rel="stylesheet" href="' . asset('general/css/components/select-boxes.css') . '" type="text/css"/>
                           <link rel="stylesheet" href="' . asset('general/css/components/select2-bootstrap.min.css') . '" type="text/css"/>',];

   view()->share('css',$css);
```

and you can make same it for js

Comment: yes it will available and you can use it in your foreach

Comment: But in my case my custom js and css are located in my view filder with blade templates.so i need to point to that location..When i correctly point to the custom js and css files, which show the page you are looking for could not be found

Comment: so you need to define `$css` and `$js` in every view and put them in your foreach.
but why you need to make this?

Comment: you can use `@stack` to push your custom style

Comment: Yes i need to create array of $css and $js in controller (where the js and css needed). but the thing is that even if i point the correct path to the js inside my view folder it shows that  page you are looking for could not be found.

Comment: Is there any restriction for locating css and js inside view folder? or should i put all the script and css inside public folder? .. Thanks

Comment: yes you should put all your styles ans scripts in public html

Comment: For eg, i have a jquery datepicker in one of my pages, the thing is that i don't want to include this  datepicker script in all my views, that is why am using custom script method

Comment: i gave you the solution from the start put this blade in your `app.blade` file
`@stack('scripts')` and in your another view just use this:

`@push('scripts')

        <script src="your library path" type="text/javascript"></script>

`@endpush